# MapBox iOS SDK 10.0.1 Error when touching a map pin

Tags: ios, ios7, mapbox

I'm getting the following error when I click on a map pin.  This is occurring in the simulators and a real devices iOS 7 and iOS 7 64 bit.

I have a map with a series of pins in it.  Since updating to 1.0.1 in an attempt to support 64 bit iPhones I get the following error:

***: CGContextPathContainsPoint: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.***

I've seen questions about this but they seem to involve TextBoxes and this has no TextBoxes.

I do not get this error with the previous versions of the MapBox SDK.
So I have 2 questions.
**First**; What can I do to find the cause of this?  Anybody encounter this?
**Second**; Is this a show stopper?  The error message does politely state this could be an error in a future update.  Is it safe to release with this?

Thanks in advance!

I don't know whether to answer my own question or do this edit.  Looks like having an empty track may have caused this somehow.  When the map has track a RMAnnotation * and a track everything was fine.  When I load a map with an empty track, that is with no points in it the trouble and errors show up.  If there are no points I don't add the annotation and I no longer get the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is an exception. Add a breakpoint for exceptions and send in the stack track to either support@mapbox.com or (preferably) the GitHub project:

http://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk

Comment: I submitted an issue in GitHub.  The calling code does not throw an exception.  It's just an UIAlertView.

Comment: In targeting iOS 8 SDK I get the same errors. I'm using 10.0.1. On the CGContextAddPath and CGContextPathContainsPoint. As stated in the original posting this happens touching a map pin. This same code has been trouble free for sometime.

Comment: This map had a zero length track that was getting added.  That is, a track with no points.  If I don't add a track clicking on the map does not produce this error, but there seems to be a side effect of hosing up my other marker annotations.  What effect would not adding a track annotation have on my marker annotations?